# How to undo a git restore to get back changes

Tags: git

Here is my situation, I'm still new to git and while I was working on a project I didn't constantly commit.

I finished the project and added everything other than the index.html file and committed them. I pushed the changes to my repository. I then checked my git status and saw that index.html was still listed which I thought was a mistake and maybe I just did a little edit by accident or something so I did a git restore index.html.

I almost immediately realized what I did and checked the file to see that the file had been reverted to its original form. Please tell me there is a way to get my changes back. I just want to emphasize that the command I used was `git restore index.html`

Answer (score 87):

If the file you accidentally restored is currently open in your Text Editor or IDE, a simply **Undo** operation would do the trick and get you your changes back.

I accidentally typed `git restore .` while I only wanted to restore one file. Luckily for me, all the files that had been restored by the command were still open in VSCode, where I made the changes, so executing an Undo in each of those files did the trick for me and I got my changes back.

Comment: This worked for me in `vim`, thanks!

Comment: omg, I was scared there! If you want to break up a commit and avoid losing it, do your work on another branch!

Comment: Undo did the trick for one file but not for another in VSCode. Thankfully for me I was able to recover the previous changes through the Timeline tab!

Answer (score 17):

If you are using JetBrains IDE, you can get back your changes in multiple files.

You need to go to each file and revert to the last change on local history (not stored in git).

Answer (score 13):

I strongly recommend to use any **local history** plugin for your IDE if it doesn't have a built-in one. Even that version controlling tools are meant for this purpose, but some developers who just met and recently started using `git` get this wrong! Well, sometimes you will lose ton of work because of making a noob git mistake that is impossible to UNDONE.

In my case, I use [Local History](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xyz.local-history) for VSCode. It's like a backup I have all time if something goes wrong. Just use it, it will cost you some disk space but you can clean it up whenever you are **100%** sure about the current version of your code.

Answer (score 5):

If you never added your `index.html` changes to your git index then git won't have any record of them. The only way to recover them would be with whatever reversion tools your operating system or backups provide.

Answer (score 1):

### For Eclipse with Git integration

1. Open a context menu (by right click or menu key) on a file in the Project Explorer or the editor area.

[image: context menu open]

2. `Team`, then `Show Local History`

[image: local history window]

This will list all recent edits by date and time. This works even if you've lost the changes in the undo/redo list.

3. Activating one of the entries will open a new editor window showing what the file looked like at that time. Notice that this window is in read-only mode, so you can select and copy its contents.

Answer (score 0):

when I was trying to just see some git commands and accidentally I give **git restore .** so I have lost all my unstaged files and I was using IntelliJ Idea so I had just press ctrl + z and all my work came back as I had previously.
You can see the Images...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ys2X1.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpzZO.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2tws.png

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA has a Local History built-in: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html#restore-files-from-local-history

Answer (score 0):

For Web (CSS and Javascript), you might be able to get the source out of the browser inspector if you haven't reloaded the page and it's not minified. This just now saved my grits.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late response, but if you've accidentally lost files after staging them
(`git add .`), you can potentially recover them using `git fsck --lost-found`.

To retrieve your files, follow these instructions for Unix-like systems:

```
git fsck --lost-found
```

to identify any lost files. Locate the lost files in the `.git/lost-found/other` directory.
you can use

```
git cat-file -p [FILE_HASH]
```

to inspect your lost files where file hash is the filename in .git/lost-found/other