# How to undo "git restore" command on unstaged files

Tags: git

So i accidentally used "git restore" on a folder instead of a file and that folder has a lot of modifyed files, the modified files where unstaged. How can i undo that action and get the files back.

EDIT: i didn't have any IDE Open or any tool to help restore the files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to undo a git restore to get back changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60554773/how-to-undo-a-git-restore-to-get-back-changes)

Comment: No, i did not have any IDE open or anything else who could restore it

Comment: As stated in the answers to that question; if you never added the files to git then there's no way to restore them with git. If they're important enough it's time to try file recovery tools.