# Is there a way to undo "git restore" command

Tags: git

I want to undo the `git restore .` command.

I wanted to pull changes from the origin, and WebStorm notified me that I need to commit all changes before the pull. I restored all changes. And now I remembered that there are changes that need to be committed. So I want to undo the `git restore .` command.

How can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to undo a git restore to get back changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60554773/how-to-undo-a-git-restore-to-get-back-changes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't undo a `git restore` with git. The [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Undoing-Things) tells you in the *Important* section that it's a dangerous command.

> It’s important to understand that git restore  is a dangerous command. Any local changes you made to that file are gone — Git just replaced that file with the last staged or committed version. Don’t ever use this command unless you absolutely know that you don’t want those unsaved local changes.

Git recommends to either [stash](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) / [branch](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) your changes if you are unsure what to do with them currently, but still need to move to another branch or pull or etc.

Edit: this applies for the `git checkout -- <...>` approach as well. Same warning and dangers.

---

Possible solution: If you text editor is still opened with the file you have restored, then you can `undo` (through whatever undo command your editor supports, maybe <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) to get back your changes. That is - if you are lucky to have your important changes saved into memory by your editor.